# Building RGB-encoded DEM for Mapbox GL

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, tile-server

I'm trying to create a RGB-encoded DEM file like the one that mapbox has for Maputnik that is being hosted on TileserverGL. I've converted a single-band DEM into a color-mapped RGB DEM then converted it into an MBTile via QTile but don't have a height-differentiated hillshade layer in Maputnik. Is there any documentation on how to create the same DEM file that Mapbox uses?